# Find vector elements matching two conditions in Matlab

Tags: matlab, find

I have a vector `a = [1 5 3 4 2]`. I'd like to find all elements of a, which are `1<a<5`. How do I do it in Matlab?

Personally I've developed one solution, but it's cumbersome:

```
a = [1 5 3 4 2];
ix = find(a>1);
ix = ix(find(a(ix)<5));
disp(a(ix))
```

What's a better way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#bq7egb6-1):

```
>> a = [1 5 3 4 2];
>> a = a(1 < a & a < 5)
a = 
    3    4    2
```

Comment: This is just weird. I've tried `a(1 < a && a < 5)` but haven't thought of just `&`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

A simple tweak to your code would simplify it:

```
a = [1 5 3 4 2];
disp(find(a>1&a<5))
```

Comment: This returns `[3 4 5]` instead of `[3 4 2]`.

Answer (score 3):

[ismember](http://www.peteryu.ca/tutorials/matlab/find_multiple_values_with_ismember_function) is a good choice for discrete cases

```
a = [1 5 3 4 2];
find(ismember(a, 2:4))
```

Comment: Good point. I wonder if you can add something about the performance of this solution vs. the accepted one.

Comment: I have done this comparison and is preferable to use logical indexing cause is faster. Find() solution is marginal ~5% and ismember() is ~35% slower than logical indexing. (The comparison is made via extraction of same size numerical data of a 500*30 matrix and averaged per 100 iterations).