# Find matrix rows matching multiple conditions on multiple columns in Matlab

Tags: matlab, find

I have a 3xn matrix A with columns x, y and z. How do I find all rows where X1>x>X2 AND Y1>y>Y2 (where X1, X2, Y1 and Y2 define a box on the x-y grid)?

I've already tried the following approaches that didn't work:

```
Abox = A(A(:,1)<X1 & A(:,1)>X2 & A(:,2)<Y1 & A(:,2)>Y2,:));
```

and

```
indices = find(A(:,1)<X1 & A(:,1)>X2 & A(:,2)<Y1 & A(:,2)>Y2);
Abox = A(indices,:);
```

both return empty arrays.

```
Axrange = A(A(:,1)<X1 & A(:,1)>X2,:)); 
Abox = Axrange(Axrange(:,2)<Y1 & Axrange(:,2)>Y2,:);
```

returns a filled array for the first line, then an empty array for the second.

Comment: the code you need is very similar to the text you wrote. What have you tried?

Comment: The question above [Find vector elements matching two conditions in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378807/find-vector-elements-matching-two-conditions-in-matlab) doesn't cover multiple conditions on multiple columns of the same matrix, just multiple conditions on a single column. I think the problem I'm having is due to multiple columns.

Comment: I added some notes on things I've already tried to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct

```
find(A(:,1)<X1 & A(:,1)>X2 & A(:,2)<Y1 & A(:,2)>Y2)
```

However, this return the indices of the matching rows. You need to use that to get the actual rows:

```
indices = find(A(:,1)<X1 & A(:,1)>X2 & A(:,2)<Y1 & A(:,2)>Y2)
A2 = A(indices,:)
```

Comment: I just updated the question to address this... Sorry, I should have been more clear that I had already done this but `find` returned an empty matrix.

Comment: This works on my example array. Make sure there are rows in your array that actually meet the criteria. If `find` returns an empty list, it means that no values meet the conditions.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out... there was a bug higher up in my code that was shifting the values used to set the criteria. Thanks for convincing me to debug and find that!